# How many even positive integers are there that are divisors of 720?

Tags: number-theory

**How many even positive integers are there that are divisors of 720 ?**

I know how to compute the number of divisors but how to compute the number of **even or odd positive divisors of a number** ?

If we list the divisors of 720 (using mathematica) : **{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 24, 30, 36, 40, 45,48, 60, 72, 80, 90, 120, 144, 180, 240, 360, 720}** among these only **24** are even,I am looking for some tricks that can be used in solving similar kinds of problems during exam (under a minute solution).

Comment: If you already know how to compute the number of divisors, you can use [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EvenDivisorFunction.html).

Comment: @J.M: I think it is giving `The sum of powers of even divisors of a number` this is not what I want,even I have no idea if that can be used to compute the number or even or odd divisors ?!

Comment: ...and a number raised to the zeroth power is?

Comment: `..and a number raised to the zeroth power is?` I believe it's 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very simple trick for this,first compute the prime factorization of $720$,which is $2^4 \times 3^2 \times 5$,the total number of factors here is $3 \times 2 \times 5 = 30$, and number of odd factors (number of factors of the odd primes)$=3 \times 2 = 6$,subtracting gives number of even factors = $24$.This method works for any number.

**NOTE:** If the number has no odd factors i.e,the prime factorization is of the form $2^a$,then the number of number of even factors is $a$ and number of odd factors is $1$.

Answer (score 16):

An even number $2m$ is a factor of $720$ iff $m$ is a factor of $360$.
So it's the same problem as counting divisors of $360$. For
that it helps to consider the prime factorization of $360$.

Answer (score 6):

Let the prime factorization of the integer $n$ be $n=\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_{i}^{e_{i}}$. The number of divisors of $n$ is given by $$
\prod_{i=1}^{k}\left( e_{i}+1\right) .$$ For $n=720$, we have $$720=\prod_{i=1}^{3}p_{i}^{e_{i}}=2^{4}\times 3^{2}\times 5$$ and $$\frac{n}{2}=\frac{720}{2}=360=2^{3}\times 3^{2}\times 5.$$ Hence the number of divisors of $360$ is

$$\prod_{i=1}^{3}\left( e_{i}+1\right) =(3+1)(2+1)(1+1)=24.$$

All these divisors of $n/2=360$ are even divisors of $n=720$ and there are no more even divisors of $720$. So there are $24$ even divisors of $720$.

ADDED. In response to Wishingwell's comment here is a possible proof. Every divisor of $n=\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_{i}^{e_{i}}$ is of the form 
$$\begin{equation*}
\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_{i}^{a_{i}},\qquad 0\leq a_{i}\leq e_{i}
\end{equation*}$$

and a term of the product
$$
\begin{equation*}
\underset{e_{1}+1\text{ terms}}{P=\underbrace{\sum_{j=0}^{e_{1}}p_{1}^{j}}}
\times \underset{e_{2}+1\text{ terms}}{\underbrace{
\sum_{j=0}^{e_{2}}p_{2}^{j}}}\times \cdots \times \underset{e_{k}+1\text{
terms}}{\underbrace{\sum_{j=0}^{e_{k}}p_{k}^{j}}}.
\end{equation*}$$

Since each sum has $e_{i}+1$ terms $(1\leq i\leq k)$, the number of terms of $P$ is $\sum_{i=1}^{k}(e_{i}+1)$.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing a combinatorial argument that gives the sum you have written. Just a curiosity!

Comment: @Wishingwell   Every divisor of $n=\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_{i}^{e_{i}}$ is of the form 
\begin{equation*}
\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_{i}^{a_{i}},\qquad 0\leq a_{i}\leq e_{i}
\end{equation*}

and a term of the product
\begin{equation*}
\underset{e_{1}+1\text{ terms}}{P=\underbrace{\sum_{j=0}^{e_{1}}p_{1}^{j}}}
\times \underset{e_{2}+1\text{ terms}}{\underbrace{
\sum_{j=0}^{e_{2}}p_{2}^{j}}}\times \cdots \times \underset{e_{k}+1\text{
terms}}{\underbrace{\sum_{j=0}^{e_{k}}p_{k}^{j}}}.
\end{equation*}

Since each sum has $e_{i}+1$ terms $(1\leq i\leq k)$, the number of terms of 
$P$ is $\sum_{i=1}^{k}(e_{i}+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

You have an even number given, so just cut it in half and count the divisors of this.

Comment: If n is a divisor of 360, then 2n is an even divisor of 720 and vice versa.  So there are the same number in each set.

Answer (score 0):

1*2*2*2*2*3*3*5. Odd divisors: (1,3,3,5) => (1,3,5,9,15,45). 
Let A = (1,3,5,9,15,45). Then all factors are, A, 2*A, 4*A, 8*A, 16*A.

Comment: Could you please explain in a bit elaborately ?